# Oracle EBS Seeded APi call java.sql.SQLException: Non supported SQL92 token at position: 6

Tags: java, database, oracle

I am trring to call orcale EBS API hr_person_address_api.create_person_address from java data base call but getting this error
    Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Non supported SQL92 token at position: 6
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.handleODBC(OracleSql.java:1275)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.parse(OracleSql.java:1161)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.getSql(OracleSql.java:328)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.getSqlBytes(OracleSql.java:630)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:205)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:1043)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3714)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4755)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1378)
        at workdaytooracleebsapipoc.hrPersonCall.main(hrPersonCall.java:108)

```
Can anyone help me with this.
PACAKAGE API DETAILS:
 hr_person_address_api.create_person_address( P_VALIDATE  IN    BOOLEAN := FALSE, 
  P_EFFECTIVE_DATE  IN    DATE, 
  P_PRADD_OVLAPVAL_OVERRIDE  IN    BOOLEAN := FALSE, 
  P_VALIDATE_COUNTY  IN    BOOLEAN := TRUE, 
  P_PERSON_ID  IN    NUMBER := NULL, 
  P_PRIMARY_FLAG  IN    VARCHAR2, 
  P_STYLE  IN    VARCHAR2, 
  P_DATE_FROM  IN    DATE, 
  P_DATE_TO  IN    DATE := NULL, 
  P_ADDRESS_TYPE  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_COMMENTS  IN    LONG := NULL, 
  P_ADDRESS_LINE1  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDRESS_LINE2  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDRESS_LINE3  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_TOWN_OR_CITY  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_REGION_1  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_REGION_2  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_REGION_3  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_POSTAL_CODE  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_COUNTRY  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_TELEPHONE_NUMBER_1  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_TELEPHONE_NUMBER_2  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_TELEPHONE_NUMBER_3  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE_CATEGORY  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE1  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE2  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE3  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE4  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE5  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE6  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE7  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE8  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE9  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE10  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE11  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE12  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE13  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE14  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE15  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE16  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE17  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE18  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE19  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADDR_ATTRIBUTE20  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADD_INFORMATION13  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADD_INFORMATION14  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADD_INFORMATION15  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADD_INFORMATION16  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADD_INFORMATION17  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADD_INFORMATION18  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADD_INFORMATION19  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_ADD_INFORMATION20  IN    VARCHAR2 := NULL, 
  P_PARTY_ID  IN    NUMBER := NULL, 
  P_ADDRESS_ID  OUT    NUMBER, 
  P_OBJECT_VERSION_NUMBER  OUT    NUMBER 
); 


Java Code
    String procedure ="call{ hr_person_address_api.create_person_address(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?); }";

            System.out.println(procedure);
            //String procedure = "{begin call hr_person_address_api.create_person_address(false,'12-MAR-19',false,true,126444,'Y','US','12-MAR-19',null,'PHCA',null,'10330 Legacy Hill',null,null,'San Antonio','Bexar','TX',null,78240,'US',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,p_address_id,p_object_version_number); ";
            CallableStatement hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address = conn.prepareCall(procedure);



            //                CallableStatement hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address = conn.prepareCall (procedure);

              System.out.println(hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.toString());

            /*
             * Register IN Parameters
             */
              System.out.println(new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getDate()));
              System.out.println(new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime()));
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_validate", false);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setDate("p_effective_date",new  java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime())); //
              //hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_effective_date", sqlDate); 
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject(   "p_pradd_ovlapval_override", false);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_validate_county",  true);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_person_id",new  BigDecimal(1222301));
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_primary_flag", "Y");
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_style", "Indai");
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setDate("p_date_from",new  java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime())); //
            //  hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_date_from",sqlDate);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_date_to",null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_address_type",  "sss");
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_comments", null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_address_line1", "sss");
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_address_line2",  null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_address_line3",  null); 
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_town_or_city",      "");
    rex       hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_region_1", "ss");
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_region_2", null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_region_3", null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_postal_code","33333");
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_country", "Indai");
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_telephone_number_1", null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_telephone_number_2",null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_telephone_number_3", null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject( "p_addr_attribute_category", null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_addr_attribute1", null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_addr_attribute2",null); 
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_addr_attribute3", null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_addr_attribute4",null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_addr_attribute5",null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_addr_attribute6",  null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_addr_attribute7",null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_addr_attribute8",  null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_addr_attribute9",  null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_addr_attribute10",  null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_addr_attribute11",  null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_addr_attribute12",null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_addr_attribute13", null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_addr_attribute14", null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_addr_attribute15", null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_addr_attribute16",  null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_addr_attribute17",  null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_addr_attribute18",  null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_addr_attribute19",null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_addr_attribute20",null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_add_information13",  null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_add_information14",null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_add_information15",  null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_add_information16",  null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_add_information17", null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_add_information18",  null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_add_information19",  null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_add_information20", null);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_party_id",null);
             /* 
              Register OUT Parameters
              */
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.registerOutParameter(            "p_address_id", java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
              hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.registerOutParameter(            "p_object_version_number", java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
              Boolean b=hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.execute();
System.out.println(b);

              arrayList.add(hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.getInt(54));
              arrayList.add(hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.getInt(55));


            hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be outdated information, but last I knew, Oracle's JDBC driver did not support passing `Boolean` types to PL/SQL procedures or functions.

You need to create a wrapper procedure with a signature like:

```
xxcust_person_address_api.create_person_address_wrapper 
 ( --P_VALIDATE  IN    BOOLEAN := FALSE, 
   P_VALIDATE  IN    VARCHAR2 := 'N', 
   P_EFFECTIVE_DATE  IN    DATE, 
   --P_PRADD_OVLAPVAL_OVERRIDE  IN    BOOLEAN := FALSE, 
   P_PRADD_OVLAPVAL_OVERRIDE  IN    VARCHAR2 := 'N',
   --P_VALIDATE_COUNTY  IN    BOOLEAN := TRUE, 
   P_VALIDATE_COUNTY  IN    VARCHAR2 := 'Y',
   P_PERSON_ID  IN    NUMBER := NULL, 
   ...
```

Then, in that wrapper, convert the necessary VARCHAR2 inputs to BOOLEAN and call `hr_person_address_api.create_person_address` from within the wrapper.

Also, in your Java code, correct lines like this:

```
hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_address_line1", "sss");
```

... don't use `setObject` to set values for `VARCHAR2` parameters, use `setString`.

Similarly with this:

```
hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_party_id",null);
```

... use `setNull` instead.  (Or if you wanted to set p_party_id to a non-null value, you'd use `setLong` or `setBigDecimal`).

In general, don't use `setObject` unless you're actually passing in a non-scalar object type (i.e., something with fields or an array).

One last thing ... I usually pass identify parameters by position.  E.g.,

```
hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject(5 ,new  BigDecimal(1222301));
```

instead of

```
hr_person_address_apiCreate_person_address.setObject("p_person_id",new  BigDecimal(1222301));
```

I am not sure the JDBC driver is smart enough to read the parameter names from the PL/SQL function and map the values you are setting by name to the correct parameters in the function.  I'm not sure how it could even do that, because it does not know the types to expect and the function could be overloaded.  If you continue having trouble, set the parameter values by position instead of by name.

Comment: Matthew,
Apart from BOOLEAN are there any other data type which are not supported from  ORACLE jdbc driver

Comment: Yes, for example, PL/SQL `RECORD` types cannot be passed.  Read all about it, and much more, here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxref.htm#JJDBC28905.